# is this .htaccess part vunerable to my site

Tags: .htaccess

in some Joomla installations I found this .htaccess in an administrator component. Can one explain what happens here and if it looks like vunerable code?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)? [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(csv)$ [R,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a bit dirty to me, but it's not a security issue for sure.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)? [NC]
```

... this means that the proceeding rule is executed only if there's no referer starting with http://www.
The referer method might be used to process the rule only 1 time, but not in further redirects, triggered by the htaccess file, because redirects don't preserve the referer. The whole intention is difficult to guess without seeing the rest of the file.

```
RewriteRule .*\.(csv)$ [R,L,NC]
```

... this means that there should be no more processing of the htaccess file if the url ends in .csv
The [L] means - "last" rule, no further processing. As @adrianopolis said, the NC means case-insensitiv, so it will match to .CSV as well as to .Csv etc.
The [R] means redirect, but as there is no target URL, it won't do anything but prevent further processing.